# How can I stop the alertDialog duplicating when the UI refreshes?

Tags: android, user-interface, mobile, android-alertdialog

I've got an Alert Dialog popping up if there is no internet connection. The problem is the UI refreshes every 2 seconds and every 2 seconds a new dialog is popping up. Is there any way to stop this? here is my code:

```
public boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}


public void setUI(){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    builder.setTitle("No internet connection");
    builder.setMessage("message ")
            .setPositiveButton("Retry", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                    // intentionally do nothing;
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // User cancelled the dialog --> soft-close the app
                    finish();
                }
            });


    if (!isNetworkAvailable()){
        builder.show();
    }
}
```

And in the ErrorNotificationEvent I got this

```
@Subscribe
public void onErrorNotificationEvent(ErrorNotificationEvent event) {
    setUI();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place a timer into the setUI call, so that it doesn't display the dialog until a certain amount of time has passed.

```
public long lastUIUpdate = 0;

@Subscribe
public void onErrorNotificationEvent(ErrorNotificationEvent event) {
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() > lastUIUpdate + DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS){
            lastUIUpdate = System.currentTimeMillis();
            setUI();
        }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted!Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You should keep a reference to your Dialog when you create it, and do not show it again if it's already showing:

```
private AlertDialog _dialog;

public void setUI(){
    if (!isNetworkAvailable() && (_dialog == null || !_dialog.isShowing())) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        ...

        _dialog = builder.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Dadou! Thnx for your reply. It throws an error _dialog.isShowing()."Can not resolve method "isShowing()", any thoughts? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Strange, because it exists since API level 1... http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#isShowing() Are you calling isShowing() on the AlertDialog object? Where is this error thrown, in LogCat or before compilation?